# Combining values from 2 rows using python

Tags: python, data-processing

I have a 2D array data that looks like this in excel :

```
01-Jan-1990 0:00:01 A abcdefghi jklmnopq
01-Jan-1990 0:00:02 A abcdefghi xxxyyyvvv fefwwe qqqqq
01-Jan-1990 0:00:02   xwwwww xxxxxxx yyyy
01-Jan-1990 0:00:05 B qwerty qwerty
01-Jan 1990 0:00:06 C popopop qwqwqwq tytytyty sss
```

and in data,

```
[['01-Jan-1990 0:00:01','A','abcdefghi jklmnopq'],
 ['01-Jan-1990 0:00:02','A','abcdefghi xxxyyyvvv fefwwe qqqqq'],
 ['01-Jan-1990 0:00:02','\t','xwwwww xxxxxxx yyyy'],      #\t instead of empty
 ['01-Jan-1990 0:00:05','B','qwerty qwerty'],
 ['01-Jan 1990 0:00:06','C','popopop qwqwqwq tytytyty sss']]
```

Would wanna ask if there is any ways i can combine the value from row 3 into the string of row 2 that do not have the `A,B,C`?

Desired output as followed:

```
01-Jan-1990 0:00:01 A abcdefghi jklmnopq
01-Jan-1990 0:00:02 A abcdefghi xxxyyyvvv fefwwe qqqqq xwwwww xxxxxxx yyyy
01-Jan-1990 0:00:05 B qwerty qwerty
01-Jan 1990 0:00:06 C popopop qwqwqwq tytytyty sss
```

**EDITED WITH DESIRED OUTPUT and missing field**

Comment: Can you post your desired output?  I'm not sure what you're asking.

Comment: Hi, Have updated the question. Sorry for inconvenience caused

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Here is a digestible solution with comments :)

```
EMPTY_MARKER = '\t'
LABEL_INDEX, VALUES_INDEX = 1, 2

# first pass to append rows with empty labels to previous row
for row in range(len(data) - 1):
    if data[row + 1][LABEL_INDEX] == EMPTY_MARKER:
        data[row][VALUES_INDEX] += ' {}'.format(data[row + 1][VALUES_INDEX])

# second pass to remove empty label rows
for row in data:
    if row[LABEL_INDEX] == EMPTY_MARKER:
        data.remove(row)

# visually readable way to display output :)
for row in data:
    print row
```

output:

```
['01-Jan-1990 0:00:01', 'A', 'abcdefghi jklmnopq']
['01-Jan-1990 0:00:02', 'A', 'abcdefghi xxxyyyvvv fefwwe qqqqq xwwwww xxxxxxx yyyy']
['01-Jan-1990 0:00:05', 'B', 'qwerty qwerty']
['01-Jan 1990 0:00:06', 'C', 'popopop qwqwqwq tytytyty sss']
```

Comment: Can I please know why I was downvoted? Especially since this is the solution the OP chose.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your data is stored in variable `data`, you can use `itertools.groupby` to group the sublists by their first item and then use `str.join` to join the last item of each group with a space:

```
from itertools import groupby
from operator import itemgetter
[[*l[0][:-1], ' '.join(m for *_, m in l)] for k, g in groupby(data, key=itemgetter(0)) for l in (list(g),)]
```

This returns:

```
[['01-Jan-1990 0:00:01', 'A', 'abcdefghi jklmnopq'],
 ['01-Jan-1990 0:00:02', 'A', 'abcdefghi xxxyyyvvv fefwwe qqqqq xwwwww xxxxxxx yyyy'],
 ['01-Jan-1990 0:00:05', 'B', 'qwerty qwerty'],
 ['01-Jan 1990 0:00:06', 'C', 'popopop qwqwqwq tytytyty sss']]
```

Comment: Hi! Thanks for your help! but i realise there is actually a '\t' instead of an empty field. Sorry for causing any inconvenience and i really appreciate your help. But do you mind review how the \t will affect your code? Thank you

Comment: @ThanksForHelping, it won't be problem if the time(the [0]) are the same.

Comment: @ThanksForHelping Like MatrixTai says, the `'\t'` in the empty field would not be a problem as long as the first row of a group has the right value for that second column, since the values of the subsequent rows in a group are discarded as I'm using `[0]` to explicitly take the values of only the first row of a group.

Answer (score 0):

Since you're looking to alter the list (by removing elements), iterating with `for row in rows` would not work unless you kept a running list of indices to remove and then did that later (or constructed a separate list if you wanted to avoid altering the original, etc.). Working backwards starting with `len(rows) - 1` and stopping at 1 means you can just check `rows[i]` and, if necessary, append its value to that of `rows[i-1]`:

```
rows = [
    ['01-Jan-1990 0:00:01','A','abcdefghi jklmnopq'],
    ['01-Jan-1990 0:00:02','A','abcdefghi xxxyyyvvv fefwwe qqqqq'],
    ['01-Jan-1990 0:00:02', '','xwwwww xxxxxxx yyyy'],
    ['01-Jan-1990 0:00:05','B','qwerty qwerty'],
    ['01-Jan 1990 0:00:06','C','popopop qwqwqwq tytytyty sss'],
]

for i in range(len(rows) - 1, 0, -1):
    if not rows[i][1]:
        rows[i-1][2] += rows[i][2]
        del rows[i]

print("\n".join(" ".join(e for e in row) for row in rows))
# 01-Jan-1990 0:00:01 A abcdefghi jklmnopq
# 01-Jan-1990 0:00:02 A abcdefghi xxxyyyvvv fefwwe qqqqqxwwwww xxxxxxx yyyy
# 01-Jan-1990 0:00:05 B qwerty qwerty
# 01-Jan 1990 0:00:06 C popopop qwqwqwq tytytyty sss
```

This assumes `rows[0]` will never have a missing value, which seems to make sense in the context of your question.

Comment: Hi! Thanks for your help! but i realise there is actually a '\t' instead of an empty field. Sorry for causing any inconvenience and i really appreciate your help. But do you mind review how the \t will affect your code? Thank you

Comment: You're welcome! `if not rows[i][1]` would not work correctly with a tab character instead of `None` or an empty string (which evaluate to `False`), but this is something you should definitely be able to correct given a very basic understanding of Python. If that's not something you can do, I'd recommend working through [the official Python tutorial](https://docs.python.org/3.6/tutorial/) so you have a base to work from.

Comment: Hi thank you for the explanation and help! Greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

blhsing's solution is great, but let's say you have data like

```
01-Jan-1990 0:00:02 A abcdefghi xxxyyyvvv fefwwe qqqqq
01-Jan-1990 0:00:03 \t xwwwww xxxxxxx yyyy
```

It won't work as it takes [0](the time) for grouping.

So I provide a method for not using the time.

```
[[*x[:-1], x[2] + ' ' + data[i+1][2] if (data[i+1][1] == '\t' if i < len(data)-1 else False) else x[2] ] for i, x in enumerate(data) if x[1] != '\t']
```

Comment: Hi! Thank you for adding on and the explanation! Greatly appreciated!

Comment: @ThanksForHelping, the chosen ans need to loop 3 times... and it must be the slowest one among all ans... why you think it is correct...